# Can't deserialize a list of elements using simple

Tags: java, simple-framework

I have the following XML which I get from a REST API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <securitygroup>
        <objectId>securitygroup-1</objectId>
        <name>Activity Monitoring Data Collection</name>      
    </securitygroup>
    <securitygroup>
        <objectId>securitygroup-10</objectId>
        <name>object2</name>      
    </securitygroup>
</list>
```

My classes are defined like this

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class SecurityGroup
{
    @Element
    String objectId;

    @Element
    String name;
}


@Root
public class SecurityGroupList
{
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    public List<SecurityGroup> list;
}
```

When I try to desalinize it

```
String input = "The above XML..."
final Persister persister = new Persister();
SecurityGroupList list =  persister.read(SecurityGroupList.class, input);
```

I get an exception with the following message "Element 'SecurityGroup' does not have a match in class cms_proxy.CMS.nsx.objects.SecurityGroupList at line 1" (ignore the line number, it's all in a single line in the String I'm using). I've tried to set the name and entry in @ElementList to "securitygroup" but still get the same message.

This sounds very trivial and I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Due a decision to decision to move from simple to Jaxb, I didn't have time to check the answers, sorry about that. Thanks again.

Comment: i would say try reverse engineer it..   Serializer serializer = new Persister();  
  File result = new File("e:\\example.xml");
  serializer.write(groupList, result);
You will see what is going wrong with your element to xml mapping(i tried it already). Make sure you create two or three elements in your list. CHEERS !!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be telling you, blatantly, what is wrong? I could be mistaken though. Still, the second entry of your XML has "objectTypeName" instead of "name" as an entry; The list is implicitly strict, so if the Persister is looking for a "SecurityGroup" class which has a field in which deserialization is supposed populate and subsequently searches for the field "objectTypeName" it will not find said field and fail as the class it is attempting to populate is not found since your example stipulate no such field.

Sources:

1. http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/core/Persister.html

Answer (score 0):

> This sounds very trivial and I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, but I can't get it to work.

Yes, an here is your mistake:

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class SecurityGroup
{
    // ...
}
```

This will use `SecurityGroup` - the name of the class - as element name. Therefor the element is named  `<SecurityGroup>...</SecurityGroup>`. But your XML contains it as lower case: `<securitygroup>...</securitygroup>`. Both don't match and simple throws an Exception to indicate that.

**Solution:** You can set a custom name with annotation-argument:

```
@Root(name = "securitygroup",strict = false)
public class SecurityGroup
{
    // ...
}
```

Now the correct name is used and the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

XML is case sensitive

```
@Root
public class SecurityGroupList
{
    @ElementList(inline = true, entry="securitygroup")
    public List<SecurityGroup> list;
}
```